# angular cli not working on windows 10

Tags: node.js, windows, angular, npm, angular-cli

I have just reinstall node.js, npm and angular-cli but this last one does not work on my PC running on Windows 10. The version of node.js is 8.1.2, the version of npm is 5.0.3. I installed angular-cli with the command line `npm install -g @angular/cli`. Now when I try any command line beginning with `ng` I have the error:

```
module.js:487
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module '@ngtools/json-schema'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:485:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:437:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:513:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Raphaël\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\config\config.js:6:23)
    at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
```

Any idea what is wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Shot in the dark, but I heard of -g installs interfering with local angular cli. However, this appears to just be a missing module from the download, maybe just a package lost. Try to uninstall and re-install again

Answer (score 2):

I'm also on Windows 10. Node 8.1.4 and npm 5.2.0
What worked for me was following the steps from an issue thread I found on github: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4425
. The link describes the following steps:

Uninstall angular cli

```
npm uninstall @angular/cli -g
```

Install rxJS

```
npm install rxjs -g
```

Cleared cache

```
npm cache clean
```

Manually deleted content in

```
%AppData%\npm\node_modules
```

Installed angular cli npm install

```
@angular/cli -g
```

Answer (score 0):

Try downgrading node to v7 and npm to v4 then run:

`rm -rf node_modules dist`

`npm cache clear --force`

`npm install`

There are also some threads mentioning the removal of `package.lock` which is a new part of npm@5. Furhtermore it is worth checking you typescript version ensuring it is > 2.2.0.